# Creating Disk Image for Unrooted Android Phone

Tags: rooting

Phone: Huawei Honor View 10

I would like to create a disk image of this phone without rooting it is there any possible way as my assignment would need me to collect data for the phone internal memory and I am using autopsy 4.21 as my tool.

Comment: Direct disk access is impossible without root.

Comment: Even if you could make an image from user data partition you phone may already use FBE then each file would be encrypted using an individual key, so a data recovery software will not be able to find anything.

Comment: thanks for the help @Robert